# How to diff in a comment on github?

Tags: github

I've seen people show diffs of their code from other forks to illustrate a point in github like on this pull request thread: https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/pull/3035

I think it would be really helpful to show the diff of the commit from the current branch. How do you do it?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can pull the branch to your local copy, and make your modification. After that, copy the output of `git diff` and paste to GitHub as follows.

````
```diff
your diff file contents
```
````

Comment: Thank you. This is close but doesn't seem to color-code it the way that the examples do.

Comment: @catbadger did you type the `diff` specifier? I tried your diff in the comments and it works well.

Comment: Is it possible to display a side-by-side diff?

Answer (score 39):

It's worth mentioning how to write the diff:

````
```diff
- line removed
+ line added
```
````